# responsive div as drop down list

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make div as drop down list and I am trying to make it responsive but no successes for now.I am trying to make it stick to the categories container.

```
the demo is here    http://jsfiddle.net/yppw2cjt/1/
```

I am trying to make it look like something like this image:

```
http://s15.postimg.org/80b238nff/categoriesexample.png
```

And I was trying to make it display none and when hover on categories display block but for some reason it didn't work

anyone have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: post your javascript

Comment: i have no java script code for that
can't it be by css? only

Comment: If you're changing the appearance of static blocks of HTML, then it may be CSS-only. But the second you try to change static content (ie. existence of divs in the DOM, the text or URL of a hyperlink, etc.) you have to use Javascript (or server-side script, but that's a lot more difficult).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I'll helps you, you can change css as per your need.

```css
 .clearfix:after{content: '';clear: both;display: block;}
 .clr{clear: both;}
 #seraching-container{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#search-input{
    width: 100%;
    /*margin: 2% 1%;*/
    /*margin: 0 1%;*/

    font-weight: 700;
    float: left;
}
#category-list{
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
  background: #e2e2e2;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.90;
  top: 23px;
  z-index: 10; /*because its absolute*/
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 1%;
}
a.category-item {
  float: left;
  width: 26%;
  margin: auto 2%;
  line-height: 0.5;
  padding-left: 2%;
  text-decoration: none;
}a.category-item p{
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(58, 56, 56);
}a.category-item p:hover{
  color: #5DA5D1; 
  text-decoration: 
  none;cursor: pointer;
}
div#categories-ctainer {
  width: 90%;
  /*margin: 2% 1%;*/
  margin: 0 1%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
}div#categories-ctainer p{
  color: #A9A9AB;
  font-weight: 700;
  float: left;
  margin:0;
  position: relative;

}div#categories-ctainer img{
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  height: 19px;
  position: relative;
}
#button-search{
    width: 6%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 1%;
}

.searchWrap , .dropdown_warp{position: relative;float: left;width: 48%;margin: 1%;}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .searchWrap , .dropdown_warp{width:100%;}
}
```

```html
<div id="searching-c" class="clearfix">
<div class="searchWrap">
 <input id="search-input" type="text" name="search_field" value="" placeholder="search">
</div>
 
 <div class="dropdown_warp">
  <div id="categories-ctainer" name="categories">
   <p>Categories</p>
   <img src="../images/arrowdown.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="button-search" value="send">S</button>  
  <div class="clr"></div>
 <div id="category-list">
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a>
 <a class="category-item"><p> Food</p></a> 
</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much that was helpful
can you explain the answer? so i will be smarter and next time i won't need to ask

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".dropdownlist").mouseover(function() {
            $("#category-list").show();
        }).mouseout(function() {
             $("#category-list").hide();
        });    
    });
```

try this. add class for dropdown image.

Comment: well that's not working so well cause its only show it when mouse over but cant really press on any item of the list.
does it responsive?
the main idea is to make it responsive the java script code  is less important but thanks for the code you are really nice

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you have `#category-list` outside of `#categories-ctainer`?

If you move `#category-list` into `#categories-ctainer` then you can make it work just fine.  Here's an [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJOybe?editors=110) (I never seem to be able to get jsfiddle to work for me).

After that just use what you were trying before, `display: none` and `display:block` on `#categories-ctainer:hover`.  Add in some absolute positioning and, voila.

HTML:

```
<div id="searching-c">
  <input id="search-input" type="text" name="search_field" value="" placeholder="search">
  <div id="categories-ctainer" name="categories">
    <p>Categories</p>
    <img src="../images/arrowdown.png" alt="">
    <div id="category-list">
      <a class="category-item">
        <p> Food</p>
      </a>
      ...
      <a>
        <p> Food</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="button-search" value="send"></button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#searching-c {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#search-input {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 2% 1%;
  font-weight: 700;
  float: left;
}

#category-list {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
  background: #e2e2e2;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.90;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  /*because its absolute*/

  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

div#categories-ctainer:hover #category-list {
  display: block;
}

a.category-item {
  float: left;
  width: 26%;
  margin: auto 2%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.category-item p {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(58, 56, 56);
}

a.category-item p:hover {
  color: #5DA5D1;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div#categories-ctainer {
  width: 48%;
  margin: 2% 1%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

div#categories-ctainer p {
  color: #A9A9AB;
  font-weight: 700;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

div#categories-ctainer img {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  height: 19px;
  position: relative;
}

#button-search {
  width: 3%;
  float: left;
  margin: 2% 1%;
}
```

I also removed the `line-height:.5` you had on `.category-item`.

This works well, because now that it is within `#categories-ctainer` when you are hovering over `#category-list` you are still hovering on `#categories-ctainer` so it doesn't disappear on you.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: that is very useful and helping i was trying to do hover with + and >. 
this solution work very well Thanks